# remove last few characters in PySpark dataframe column

Tags: python, pyspark, substring

I am having a PySpark DataFrame. How can I chop off/remove last 5 characters from the column `name` below -

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import substring, length
valuesCol = [('rose_2012',),('jasmine_2013',),('lily_2014',),('daffodil_2017',),('sunflower_2016',)]
df = sqlContext.createDataFrame(valuesCol,['name'])
df.show()

+--------------+
|          name|
+--------------+
|     rose_2012|
|  jasmine_2013|
|     lily_2014|
| daffodil_2017|
|sunflower_2016|
+--------------+
```

I want to create 2 columns, the `flower` and `year` column.

**Expected output:**

```
+--------------+----+---------+
|          name|year|   flower|
+--------------+----+---------+
|     rose_2012|2012|     rose|
|  jasmine_2013|2013|  jasmine|
|     lily_2014|2014|     lily|
| daffodil_2017|2017| daffodil|
|sunflower_2016|2016|subflower|
+--------------+----+---------+
```

`year` column I have created -

```
df = df.withColumn("year", substring(col("name"),-4,4))
df.show()
+--------------+----+
|          name|year|
+--------------+----+
|     rose_2012|2012|
|  jasmine_2013|2013|
|     lily_2014|2014|
| daffodil_2017|2017|
|sunflower_2016|2016|
+--------------+----+
```

I don't know how to chop last 5 characters, so that I only have the name of flowers. I tried something like this, by invoking `length`, but that doesn't work.

```
df = df.withColumn("flower",substring(col("name"),0,length(col("name"))-5))
```

How can I create `flower` column with only flower names?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

You can use expr function

```
>>> from pyspark.sql.functions import substring, length, col, expr
>>> df = df.withColumn("flower",expr("substring(name, 1, length(name)-5)"))
>>> df.show()
+--------------+----+---------+
|          name|year|   flower|
+--------------+----+---------+
|     rose_2012|2012|     rose|
|  jasmine_2013|2013|  jasmine|
|     lily_2014|2014|     lily|
| daffodil_2017|2017| daffodil|
|sunflower_2016|2016|sunflower|
+--------------+----+---------+
```

Comment: That's what exactly I was looking for, something by invoking length, but couldn't figure out. Thank you so much Ali.

Answer (score 12):

You can use `split` function. this code does what you want:

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as f

newDF = df.withColumn("year", f.split(df['name'], '\_')[1]).\
           withColumn("flower", f.split(df['name'], '\_')[0])

newDF.show()

+--------------+----+---------+
|          name|year|   flower|
+--------------+----+---------+
|     rose_2012|2012|     rose|
|  jasmine_2013|2013|  jasmine|
|     lily_2014|2014|     lily|
| daffodil_2017|2017| daffodil|
|sunflower_2016|2016|sunflower|
+--------------+----+---------+
```

Comment: is it necessary to escape underscore like you have done  \ _ ?

Comment: What do you mean exactly by "escape underscore"? this function split the string in the `name` column into two strings, one before `_` and another one after `_` no matter what the length of string is.

Comment: yes, that I understood, but since you were using backslash  \ as well, so thought that you are escaping it?

Comment: Yes, you thought right. by the way, it works without backslash \ too.

Answer (score 8):

In this case, since we want to extract alphabetical characters, so REGEX will also work.

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import regexp_extract 
df = df.withColumn("flower",regexp_extract(df['name'], '[a-zA-Z]+',0))
df.show()
+--------------+----+---------+
|          name|year|   flower|
+--------------+----+---------+
|     rose_2012|2012|     rose|
|  jasmine_2013|2013|  jasmine|
|     lily_2014|2014|     lily|
| daffodil_2017|2017| daffodil|
|sunflower_2016|2016|sunflower|
+--------------+----+---------+
```

Answer (score 2):

Adding little tweak to avoid hard coding and identify column length dynamically through location of underscore('_') using `instr` function.

```
df = spark.createDataFrame([('rose_2012',),('jasmine_2013',),('lily_2014',),('daffodil_2017',),('sunflower_2016',)],['name'])


df.withColumn("flower",expr("substr(name, 1, (instr(name,'_')-1) )")).\
        withColumn("year",expr("substr(name, (instr(name,'_')+1),length(name))")).show()
```

Answer (score -1):

```
>>> from pyspark.sql.functions import substring, length, expr
>>> df = df.withColumn("flower",expr("substring(name, 0, length(name)-5)"))
>>> df.show()
```

Comment: This looks like a duplicate answer to me. If you're trying to suggest a change or improvement, please explain it.

Comment: Starting index of a substring function should start from 0

Comment: That's a very good point. I wonder why that wasn't noticed before. Did you test with your solution and the accepted answer's, and confirm that your answers fixes the problem?

Comment: Hum, actually, `1` is correct. The [pyspark user manual for substr](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.4.0/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.substring) says "Note The position is not zero based, but 1 based index." A terrible decision if you ask me, but that's irrelevant here...