# How do I count how many items are in a specific row in my RDD

Tags: python, scala, pyspark

as you can tell I’m fairly new to using Pyspark Python my RDD is set out as follows:
(ID, First name, Last name, Address)
(ID, First name, Last name, Address)
(ID, First name, Last name, Address)
(ID, First name, Last name, Address)
(ID, First name, Last name, Address)
 Is there anyway I can count how many of these records I have stored within my RDD such as count all the IDs in the RDD. So that the output would tell me I have 5 of them. 
I have tried using RDD.count() but that just seems to return how many items I have in my dataset in total.

Comment: Post your attempt at solving this, i.e. code please.

Comment: RDD.count() #This did not return what I wanted

Comment: No, something more than that. For example, a custom function for counting each record.

Comment: Look at this question for example. you should ask a question in a more proper way. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53153149/remove-last-few-characters-in-pyspark-dataframe-column

Comment: It's not clear what you need. Give an example

Answer (score 0):

If you have RDD of tuples like RDD[(ID, First name, Last name, Address)] then you can perform below operation to do different types of counting.

1. Count the total number of elements/Rows in your RDD.

   rdd.count()
2. Count Distinct IDs from your above RDD. Select the ID element and then do a distinct on top of it.

   rdd.map(lambda x : x[0]).distinct().count()

Hope it helps to do the different sort of counting.

Let me know if you need any further help here.

Regards,

Neeraj