# Performing different computations conditioned on a column value in a spark dataframe

Tags: dataframe, pyspark, partitioning

I have a pyspark dataframe with 2 columns, A and B. I need rows of B to be processed differently, based on values of the A column. In plain pandas I might do this:

```
import pandas as pd
funcDict = {}
funcDict['f1'] = (lambda x:x+1000)
funcDict['f2'] = (lambda x:x*x)
df = pd.DataFrame([['a',1],['b',2],['b',3],['a',4]], columns=['A','B'])
df['newCol'] = df.apply(lambda x: funcDict['f1'](x['B']) if x['A']=='a' else funcDict['f2']
(x['B']), axis=1)
```

The easy way I can think of to do in (py)spark are

*Use files*

- read in the data into a dataframe
- partition by column A and write to separate files (`write.partitionBy`)
- read in each file and then process them separately

or else

*use expr*

- read in the data into a dataframe
- write a unwieldy expr (from a readability/maintenance perspective) to conditionally do something differently based on the value of the column
- this will not look anywhere as "clean" as the pandas code above looks

Is there anything else that is the appropriate way to handle this requirement? From the efficiency perspective, I expect the first approach to be cleaner, but have more run time due to the partition-write-read, and the second approach is not as good from the code perspective, and harder to extend and maintain.

More primarily, would you choose to use something completely different (e.g. message queues) instead (relative latency difference notwithstanding)?

***EDIT 1***

Based on my limited knowledge of pyspark, the solution proposed by user pissall (https://stackoverflow.com/users/8805315/pissall) works as long as the processing isn't very complex. If that happens, I don't know how to do it without resorting to UDFs, which come with their own disadvantages. Consider the simple example below

```
# create a 2-column data frame
# where I wish to extract the city 
# in column B differently based on
# the type given in column A
# This requires taking a different 
# substring (prefix or suffix) from column B
df = sparkSession.createDataFrame([
  (1, "NewYork_NY"),
  (2, "FL_Miami"),
  (1, "LA_CA"),
  (1, "Chicago_IL"),
  (2,"PA_Kutztown")
], ["A", "B"])

# create UDFs to get left and right substrings
# I do not know how to avoid creating UDFs
# for this type of processing
getCityLeft = udf(lambda x:x[0:-3],StringType())
getCityRight = udf(lambda x:x[3:],StringType())

#apply UDFs
df = df.withColumn("city", F.when(F.col("A") == 1, getCityLeft(F.col("B"))) \
                            .otherwise(getCityRight(F.col("B"))))
```

Is there a way to do this in a simpler manner without resorting to UDFs? If I use `expr`, I can do this, but as I mentioned earlier, it doesn't seem elegant.

Answer (score 0):

What about using `when`?

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

df = df.withColumn("transformed_B", F.when(F.col("A") == "a", F.col("B") + 1000).otherwise(F.col("B") * F.col("B")))
```

**EDIT after more clarity on the question**:

You can use `split` on `_` and take the first or the second part of it based on your condition.

Is this the expected output?

```
df.withColumn("city", F.when(F.col("A") == 1, F.split("B", "_")[0]).otherwise(F.split("B", "_")[1])).show()

+---+-----------+--------+
|  A|          B|    city|
+---+-----------+--------+
|  1| NewYork_NY| NewYork|
|  2|   FL_Miami|   Miami|
|  1|      LA_CA|      LA|
|  1| Chicago_IL| Chicago|
|  2|PA_Kutztown|Kutztown|
+---+-----------+--------+
```

#### UDF approach:

```
def sub_string(ref_col, city_col):
    # ref_col is the reference column (A) and city_col is the string we want to sub (B)
    if ref_col == 1:
        return city_col[0:-3]
    return city_col[3:]

sub_str_udf = F.udf(sub_string, StringType())
df = df.withColumn("city", sub_str_udf(F.col("A"), F.col("B")))
```

Also, please look into: [remove last few characters in PySpark dataframe column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53153149/remove-last-few-characters-in-pyspark-dataframe-column)

Comment: @pisall, I have edited my question to address why I don't know how to use your proposed solution in general, where the processing becomes more complex. Thanks.

Comment: @KS1 You didn't need a UDF for this. Please see if this is the expected output? I tried our code and had got this same output

Comment: Thanks for the attention. Perhaps the example isn't apt. Here, there is a _ to split on, which makes it simpler. In general, where the function depends on the actual value in the column A, will also make it hard. Trying to do this where the underscore isn't present is also something I struggled with (e.g. I can't just push something "looking like" ```substring(F.col('B'),3,length(F.col('B')))```

Comment: I think that will give you a `TypeError`. For working with dynamic length strings substring won't work out of the box. How about using a `pandas_udf`? I can help you combine two udf's into one udf

Comment: yes. The UDF is what I was trying to avoid :). Again, this is just a very simplified version of what I expect to compute, so was trying to see if there are other general approaches. Thanks!

Comment: @KS1 Substring inside eval is going to give you what you need brother.

Comment: @KS1, `df.apply` to Pandas is no difference from `udf` to pyspark, both are not vectorized, you can register udfs to be used in `expr` (SQL context) which can be very concise than using API functions. you can also write a scala or java-based udf to avoid data serDe between Python/Scala interpreters.